# Read a python rewritten image in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have code using Flask as given below:

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='/static')
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
def result():

    text = request.form['Name']
    sentiment = generateimage(text)



    return render_template("result.html")
```

**my-form.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-1"></div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <form action="http://localhost:5505/result" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Text</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="4" id="comment" name="Name"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Analyze">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**result.html**

```
 <img src ="/static/fig1.png"/>
```

What `flask.py` does is grab the text from `my-form`, process it and generate an image in a static folder, but when the `result.html` page loads up it displays the previously generated image and not the most recent one.

How do I solve this issue?

```
def generateimage(text)
       ######some code######
        plt.savefig('/home/aurora/Desktop/sentiment/static/fig1.png', dpi=dpi)
```

Comment: Could you also show `generateimage` function?

Comment: Is your `generateimage()` function blocking (i.e. does the image get actually generated before calling `render_template()`)? If yes, disable caching - for the whole page, or for the image itself. If not, add a `while True:` loop before rendering the template and wait for the image to become available.

Comment: This is probably your browser caching the old `fig1.png`. You would either have to flush your cookies or use some cache busting method.

Comment: @zwer `while True:` doesn't work, but refreshing the page on `result.html` loads the new image , it means the issue is in caching or??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that this is a caching issue, otherwise your first call to the system would not produce an image at all. A quick and dirty hack is to just force your image not to be cached by adding a random query string after the image URL within the `result.html`:

```
<img src ="/static/fig1.png?{{no_cache}}"/>
```

And then just call it from your Flask app as:

```
return render_template("result.html", no_cache=time.time())  # import time, of course
```

This, kind of, defeats the purpose of *static* content - if you're always going to render the image based on user input there is little point in storing it at all - just create a different Flask endpoint that will render the image directly to the user without ever storing it and call that instead of the image's static URL.